# Asterisks before vs after?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

This is what I'm running:

```
pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_USER,(const void**)&pam_user);
```

`pamh` is a struct not important to this question and `pamuser` is a void pointer. This code compiles and executes successfully. However, this does not:

```
pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_USER,(const **void)&pam_user);
```

Why do the asterisks change meaning before vs after? Thanks!

Comment: They don't change meaning, they lose meaning, that is, become invalid. Programming language syntaxes are like that. Arbitrary change in, garbage out (mostly).

Comment: It's just illegal syntax. Hard to argue why the syntax came to be illegal. It is what it is.

Comment: Similarly, your car changes behavior when you move the engine in front of the bumper, and your body changes behavior when you move your kidneys into your cranial cavity. You can't just take part of something that works, put it somewhere else, and have it keep working.

Comment: I suspect you meant const void** versus void const**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asterisks are components that make up the name of the type.  And the order of the components of the name of the type, affect what type it actually is.

Specifically, an asterisk modifies the type such that it becomes a pointer to whatever type is named on the left. So,

```
void*
```

That is a pointer to void (i.e. a pointer to a region of memory that may be of any type).

```
const void*
```

And that is a pointer to a `const void` (i.e. a pointer to a region of memory which either *is* const, or should be considered const from the view of this pointer).

```
const void**
```

And that is a pointer to a `const void*`.

So, with that in mind, what would you expect this to be:

```
const **void
```

A void to a pointer to a const pointer? Meaningless.

Comment: Okay, because I know things like: `int *i` and `int* i` work. cost is a modifier though, not a type. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Goodies Those are actually the same thing. The whitespace is irrelevant there.

Answer (score 2):

The typecast operator is `(type)` where `type` is a valid type. To check if the syntax of `type` makes sense, try defining a variable of type `type`.

```
(const void**)&pam_user // ok
const void **x;  // legal, meaningful

(const **void)&pam_user // wrong
const **void x; // wrong, meaningless
```

`const` qualifies the type `void` here. So what follows after `const` should also be a valid type. `** void` is not a valid type. `**` after `const` makes no sense.